# Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

Hello I have started working on a already developed system developed in zend framework. Actually I am converting the simple zend to modular approach. I have created folder of modules, set setting for that. Now I created a module `affiliate` and set it as default module in the `application.ini`. Now when i access my project, the controller in default module run. Now I created a new module `f8admin` and when I try to access it as `project/module/controller/action` it generates an exception which looks like

```
 Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'login' not found

 thrown in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Acl.php on line 365
```

Call Stack

```
Zend_Acl->get()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Acl.php on line 846
Zend_Acl->isAllowed()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Svit/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php on line 46
Svit_Controller_Plugin_Acl->preDispatch()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 309
Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->preDispatch()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php on line 941
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php on line 97
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
in /zend_medaffiliate/library/Zend/Application.php on line 366
Zend_Application->run()
in /zend_medaffiliate/abc.com/index.php on line 26
```

Now can any body tell me what is the problem and where exactly I need to work? Where exactly I need to change things to get rid off this problem? The system is already developed by another developer which is not accessible now.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently you changed enough of your application that now your `acl`(access control list) plugin is having a nervous breakdown.

Now I can't tell what's in your acl plugin (located at `/zend_medaffiliate/library/Svit/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php`) that's causing the problem but to turn it off until you can get around to fixing it should be simple.

The plugin will be registered in either your *application.ini* or your *Bootstrap.php* and you are looking for a line that addresses **"Svit_Controller_Plugin_Acl"**.

In your application.ini the line might look similar to:
`resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Svit_Controller_Plugin_Acl"`